# NodeJS: How to free buffers that get allocated outside of the V8 memory heap

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, streaming, buffer

I have an application where I am sequentially downloading mp3 files from a server, storing them in my server temporarily, then streaming them directly to clients, like so:

```
function downloadNextTrack(){
  var request = http.get('http://mp3server.com', function(response){
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      fs.appendFile('sometrack.mp3', data, function (err) {});
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
      streamTrack('sometrack.mp3');
    }
  });
};

var clients = []; // client response objects are pushed to this array when they request the stream through a route like /stream.mp3

var stream;

function streamTrack(track){
  stream = fs.createReadStream(track);
  stream.on('data', function(data){
    clients.forEach(function(client) {
      client.write(data);
    });
  });
  stream.on('end', function(){
    downloadNextTrack(); // redoes the same thing with another track
  }
};
```

Apparently this code is creating a lot of buffers which aren't being freed by the OS, when I run 'free -M' command, this is what I get (after about 4 hours of running the app):

```
                   total      used       free     shared    buffers     cached
              Mem: 750        675         75          0         12        180
-/+ buffers/cache:            481        269
             Swap: 255        112        143
```

The number under 'buffers' constantly rises (as well as the cached memory) and the OS apparently doesn't reclaim that 180mb back, until eventually my app runs out of memory and crashes when I try spawning a small process to verify a track's bitrate, sampling rate, id3 info, etc.

I have diagnosed with a lot of different tools (such as memwatch and nodetime) to find out if it was an internal memory leak and it isn't, the V8 memory heap as well as the Node RSS vary +/- 10mb but stay constant for most part while the OS free memory gets lower and lower (when the Node process starts I have about 350MB of free memory).

I read somewhere that Buffer instances allocated by Node have direct access to raw memory and so V8 doesn't have power over them (which checks out with the fact that I am not getting memory leaks from the V8 heap), the thing is, I need a way to get rid of these old buffers. Is this possible? Or will I have to restart my app every 5 hours or so (or worse, buy more RAM!)?

PS. I am running Node v0.8.16 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Hi, maybe this is a stupid question but, correct me if I'm wrong: the order is 

0) download Track #0
1) when finish, stream for all cliends
2) when finish stream, dwonload Track #1 

when you do this it is kind of recursion, right? inside the first call 'streamTrack' you have a stream variable (it is a global variable?) and, in the end, you call 'downloadNextTrack' and call 'streamTrack' again, with a different stream variable. if you call using recursion it can be a source of problems?

Comment: In the production code this stream variable acts more like a singleton, so when another stream starts, it's reassigned to the new readStream. It acts like a global variable but it's not global variable per se.

Comment: Try using `setTimeout(function (){streamTrack('somefile');}, 0);`. It will kill the "recursivity" error (I know, a little delayed answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Tiago,
I think this is caused because of the recursive nature of your code.
I don't think the streams is what gobbling up your heap, because as you said, the stream variable is being reassigned with a new ReadStream with every iteration.
However, the http.get's request and response (and whatever Buffers they use) in line 2 are never being released before calling the next iteration; they are scoped within the downloadNextTrack function. You end up with a recursive stack trace that has a set of request and response objects (and some underlying buffers) per file.

In general, if this code needs to run many, many times, why not opt-out of the recursion and do it all iteratively? a never-ending recursion will always gobble more and more memory, until the program crashes, even if there's no memory leaks on your part.

Comment: So you suggest nulling the request and response variables before calling streamTrack? I thought that once the response ended and I wasn't using those variables anymore they would just get collected by the GC eventually.
Would keeping everything in an infinite loop solve this? FYI: this is the production code: https://github.com/pedromtavares/radio/blob/master/lib/provider.js

Comment: Nulling would not help, since the stack trace grows and grows and JS will still keep [closure] references to the stream objects. Using an infinite loop (a simple iterative loop) will do the trick, because then would reference the older stream objects.

Comment: After a bit of thinking, your line of thought does in fact make sense. I don't have time to refactor the code right now (and I don't have tests for it, shame on me) to see if it will actually fix the problem, but I'll consider your answer as correct. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com

Buffer cache is a cache for inodes and dentries (filesystem structures). That memory is still available to processes. You should not care about this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11470551)

Comment: Ok fine, it's just that english is not my first language and that site explains it far better. Also don't know if copying and pasting their content is fair use.
Then, the sole purpose of that site is to explain that thing.